# Quarkus: @Valid doesn’t work with PanacheMongo

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a problem with validation of my bean.
I'm using Quarkus with MongoDB and when I try to run a create REST API, with `@Valid` annotation before request bean, I expect an exception if I want to create a document with `null` field (obviously I use `@NotNull` in entity), but document is created without field.
Here is my code:

Car.java:

```java
@MongoEntity(collection="cars")
public class Car extends PanacheMongoEntityBase {

    @BsonId
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String carName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 3)
    private String code;

    // get and set
}
```

CarResource.java:

```java
@Path("/cars")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public class CarResource {

    @GET
    public List<Car> list() {
        return Car.listAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Car get(long id) {
        return Car.findById(id);
    }

    @POST
    public Response create(@Valid Car car) {
        car.persist();
        return Response.status(201).build();
    }
```

I have same problem with `@Size` annotation, because I can create a `code` field with more characters than 3.

**UPDATE**

Validation works with quarkus-hibernate-validator.

Now, I have to find a solution for unique field.

And besides from the main question: is there an annotation like `@Indexed(unique = true)`? I want an unique field for my app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@Validated` annotation on `CarResource` Class as shown below.

```java
@Path("/cars")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Validated
public class CarResource {

    @GET
    public List<Car> list() {
        return Car.listAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Car get(long id) {
        return Car.findById(id);
    }

    @POST
    public Response create(@Valid Car car) {
        car.persist();
        return Response.status(201).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you SSK, I try it later. Is there any solution for unique field?

Comment: what do you mean by unique filed?
Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: Yeah of course. In spring there is @Indexed (unique = true) annotation used when we want that a field is unique in database. For example if I add an object with field “code: 001” and next time I want to add another object with “code: 001”, I except an exception that field already exists.

Comment: You can impleemnt @Indexed(unique=true) as a standard Bean Validation constraint that would call your database. But this is something that is usually frown upon. Unless your use your database in serialisable mode (unlikely), then such validation has timing window weaknesses.